# Is there a way to pull the last CoreData Entry only?

Tags: ios, swiftui, core-data

I have a dashboard view that I'd like to display a few variables from my last entered CoreData entry. However, I can't figure out how to fetch only the last data entered into a variable so I can display it. Any ideas?

EDIT: I'm trying to setup a NSFetchRequest inside of a called function that is called only onappear. However, I'm getting errors and am lost.

```
func singleEntryPull() -> [Item] {
        let request: NSFetchRequest<Item> = Item.fetchRequest()
        request.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "todaysDate", ascending: false)]
        request.fetchLimit = 1
        let singleEntry = FetchRequest(fetchRequest: request)
        return singleEntry
    }
```

And then the return from the function should only show 1 result and I can then use the returned value to display the variables I need?

Comment: I don’t understand why the accepted answer in the linked question should work.

Comment: I have reopen the question

Comment: In what way is this sort descriptor not working? How are your actual results different from what you want?

Comment: It is pulling all entries of the entity 'Item' whereas I only want the most recent one. I want this so that I can display on my opening view a dashboard with 4 of the 12 variables from the most recent entry.

Comment: Edited above with my most recent efforts. Still can't display the data I want using singleEntry. and then any of my variables from my Entity.

Comment: I tried `ForEach(singleEntry) { item in }` and then using item.hoursSlept etc with the above code with a fetch limit of 1. But if I have more than one entry in core data, it then starts displaying the views all over each other instead of just the most recent entry.

Comment: I would not use  @FetchRequest but instead try an old style  NSFetchRequest, maybe wrap it in a function and call that in onAppear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, not sure if this is the cleanest or best way to do this but I got it working like I want for now until a better solution comes up. I'm still using @FetchRequest which im now aware is pulling data live and updating it, but that might work as if someone keeps the app open overnight and updates it in the morning, I'd want it to display that latest entry. I used this:

```
ForEach(singleEntry.prefix(1)) { item in
```

Comment: Why are you using ForEach? I don't understand what this answer is doing that mine is not. You haven't shown the view that you're actually using this item in, so maybe I'm missing something.

Answer (score 0):

A fetch limit of 1 on a fetch request will return you a single value. However, when you're setting up a `@FetchRequest`, you're doing more than this - you're making the initial fetch and then continuing to monitor the context for changes, so it live updates. This monitoring only uses the predicate of your fetch request.

Depending on your order of operations, you could be seeing the latest data, and then any new data inserted since you started that view. My experiments with the SwiftUI core data template project prove this out - on initial run you get the a single latest entry, but as you add newer ones, the fetch-limited screen picks up the new entries.

Depending on how this view is actually used, you have two choices - you can do an actual fetch request on appear of the view and store the result as an observable object, or you can make sure you only ever use the first record from the fetch request's results array, which will always be the latest record because of your sort ordering:

```swift
var body: some View {
    if let latest = singleEntry.first {
        // Some view describing the latest entry
    } else {
        Text("No record")
    }
}
```

Comment: OMG you are definitely on to something. I have it setup now like so `List(singleEntry) { item in
                    Text("\(item.hoursSlept)")
                    Text("\(item.todaysDate!, formatter: dateFormatter)")
                    Text("\(item.alcoholDrinks)")
                    
                }```.        And it displays the most recent with the above code but if I add another, it then displays that too. However, if I restart the app with those same two entries, it only displays the most recent. So now that I know that's what's happening....how do I do the fetch on appear only?

Comment: I think using `singleEntry.first` is probably a cleaner solution, with a single fetch you would have to deal with an optional observable object which is requires a bit of messing around with nested views and such, or to perform a fetch request every time the view body is evaluated, which is not great.

Comment: Continuing to use `@FetchRequest` means that your "latest" view will always be up-to-date as well, without you needing to worry about it only being updated when it first appears.

Comment: I edited the original question with what I'm trying to do. I'm trying to switch over to NSFetchRequest within a called function that will only be called when the view it loaded. What am I doing wrong with the NSFetchRequest function?

Comment: You need to get the managed object context out of the environment (`Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context`) and use it to execute the request: `try context.fetch(request)`. `FetchRequest` is only for use by the property wrapper. But now you have to deal with errors, and where to store this returned value, I don't think it really makes your life any easier.